# How private is my code in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

I have some c++ binary running on my web server that does some calculations and I was thinking about moving it to the user side using Webassembly. My question is how private will my c++ code be? Is it possible to transform a compiled Webassembly file back to c++?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How private is it? Not private at all. Your WebAssembly code is delivered over HTTP to the client's machine where it is executed. It is obfuscated a little, but hardly private.

The code is delivered in a binary format, however using readily available tools, e.g. `wasm2wat`, this can easily be converted into a human readable text format. The text is a relatively low level language, but still quite readable. It will not protect your algorithms, it will simply take people a little longer to understand them.

WebAssembly is not readily transformable back to higher level languages (e.g. C++), but this does not make your algorithm private.