# How to hide tensorflow.js code and trained model?

Tags: javascript, c++, tensorflow, webassembly, tensorflow.js

I am trying to make sure that the classification, training process and the model is **hidden** while used in browser. I have found that wasm is kind of binary format for web browser to execute. **Can I use wasm?**

- Is there a way in tensorflow or in js to hide my training or classification algorithm and pre-trained model?
- Is there any other framework supporting it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How private is my code in WebAssembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538827/how-private-is-my-code-in-webassembly)

Comment: I need to make my model private too.. again I want to train it on user browser and also want to do classification on users browser... how am I going to import my model and keep it hidden?

Comment: Colin webassembly only support c++ not js... and tensorflow.js is a whole new thing I don't think its duplicate... And I couldn't find any examples on regarding this issue

Comment: It's probably a duplicate, because the answer is the same and the question is nearly the same.

Comment: webassembly doesn't support js because it doesn't have any garbage collection process... again webassembly can't hide a model as far as I know.. tell me how is it duplicate?

Comment: You are asking how to hide your js code. The answer is: It's not possible

Comment: The answer is applicable for every programming language. C++ is an example

Comment: okay then how to hide the trained model in wasm ?

Comment: Since your model will be read by your progam and the user can intercept the data from your program (js is very user friendly) I think you can't either.

Comment: are you saying that it is applicable for python too?

Comment: It's independent of the programming language. Your code will be compiled into wasm. There are possibilities to reconstruct your wasm. The wasm is independend of the programming language so the reconstruction is.

Comment: According to http://webassembly.org/docs/faq/    " As WebAssembly evolves it will support more languages than C/C++, and we hope that other compilers will support it as well, even for the C/C++ language, for example GCC. "

Comment: Sir you missing one thing again and again webassembly does not have any garbage collection process so running python is not a option for now at least. If they have any we could just run js in webassembly.

Comment: @navid: as one of the designers and implementors of WebAssembly I guarantee you that your question is a duplicate. You code is not private on the web because it runs on the user's machine. That user can get the code, and all you can do is try to obfuscate it. It was a non-goal of WebAssembly to make it "hidden" because that's how the web works.

Comment: @JF Bastien : thank you. 
sir can you explain one more thing? that is what happens the code inside EM_ASM function? I mean is that code get compiled or interpreted at runtime.. If compiled then if that runs faster or slower than native interpreted js in browser?

Comment: @navid that's a pretty big question for a small comment section. I suggest reading up on WebAssembly some more, and asking more pointed questions outside the comments.

Comment: okay sir I am posting it outside

Comment: @JFBastien sir can you reply this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665429/what-happens-to-the-js-code-inside-em-asm

Answer (score 3):

There is currently not yet a good way to simultaneously run your TFJS model in a users' browser, and also keep your model secret.  If model privacy is a design constraint, you will need to either do some sever-side computation, or invent some other solution.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/239

Comment: Thats why I was asking if I can use wasm to make my model obfuscate.

Answer (score 2):

An update for those who still wonder about this issue: **Tensorflow.js** now utilizes **WebAssembly** under the hood. As noted above, this does *not* mean your code is inaccessible. **Cloistered, obfuscated & unfriendly** yes, yet the determined user can still **capture, de-compile, & analyze** that code. Granted, few users have both the capability & motivation to do so, but it's a big world out there...