# what happens to the js code inside EM_ASM?

Tags: c++, webassembly, enscript

In Enscripten what happens to the code inside EM_ASM function? I mean if that code get compiled or interpreted at runtime? If compiled then if that runs faster or slower than native interpreted js in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it'll place that code inside your `.js` file and the Emscripten code will call it. It will have the exact same performance as any other JS code, excepting any performance penalty caused by switching from the Wasm to JS code.